# Combining two files in linux (or R) with duplicated with one common column

Tags: linux, r, duplicates

I have two big files with several columns and lines. Both files contain the column TAG which is in one file has no duplicates and in the other file does have duplicates.

See like this:

FILE1:

```
stat    stat    P-value tag
0.3049  7.464   1.875e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_109092036
0.2961  7.448   2.105e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_109092036
0.2934  7.347   3.389e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_109092036
0.2961  7.245   5.668e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_109092036
0.6682  7.284   4.664e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_109957962
0.6682  7.284   4.664e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_109957962
0.3933  7.363   3.127e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_159842839
0.3808  7.284   4.672e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_159842839
0.2993  7.17    8.278e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_169972458
0.3312  7.817   3.075e-12   L2_None_chr1_-_203626998
0.3312  7.817   3.075e-12   L2_None_chr1_-_203626998
0.614   7.616   9.742e-12   L2_None_chr1_-_569826
0.6411  7.58    1.037e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_569826
0.5755  7.275   4.871e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_569826
0.6893  7.26    5.255e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_6546011
0.3136  7.529   1.35e-11    L2_None_chr1_-_91180355
0.3262  7.449   2.023e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_91180355
0.298   7.151   9.129e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_91180355
0.2999  7.149   9.201e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_91182695
0.5383  7.189   7.534e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_91183491
```

FILE2:

```
L2_None_chr1_-_109092036    chr1    109092034
L2_None_chr1_-_109957962    chr1    109957879
L2_None_chr1_-_159842839    chr1    159842779
L2_None_chr1_-_169972458    chr1    169972444
L2_None_chr1_-_203626998    chr1    203626983
L2_None_chr1_-_569826   chr1    569802
L2_None_chr1_-_6546011  chr1    6545930
L2_None_chr1_-_91180355 chr1    91180310
L2_None_chr1_-_91182695 chr1    91182572
L2_None_chr1_-_91183491 chr1    91183389
```

What I want;

```
stat    P-value tag tag chr bp
7.464   1.875e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_109092036    L2_None_chr1_-_109092036    1   109092036
7.448   2.105e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_109092036    L2_None_chr1_-_109092036    1   109092036
7.347   3.389e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_109092036    L2_None_chr1_-_109092036    1   109092036
7.245   5.668e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_109092036    L2_None_chr1_-_109092036    1   109092036
7.284   4.664e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_109957962    L2_None_chr1_-_109957962    1   109957962
7.284   4.664e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_109957962    L2_None_chr1_-_109957962    1   109957962
7.363   3.127e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_159842839    L2_None_chr1_-_159842839    1   159842839
7.284   4.672e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_159842839    L2_None_chr1_-_159842839    1   159842839
7.17    8.278e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_169972458    L2_None_chr1_-_169972458    1   169972458
7.817   3.075e-12   L2_None_chr1_-_203626998    L2_None_chr1_-_203626998    1   203626998
7.817   3.075e-12   L2_None_chr1_-_203626998    L2_None_chr1_-_203626998    1   203626998
7.616   9.742e-12   L2_None_chr1_-_569826   L2_None_chr1_-_569826   1   569826
7.58    1.037e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_569826   L2_None_chr1_-_569826   1   569826
7.275   4.871e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_569826   L2_None_chr1_-_569826   1   569826
7.26    5.255e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_6546011  L2_None_chr1_-_6546011  1   6546011
7.529   1.35e-11    L2_None_chr1_-_91180355 L2_None_chr1_-_91180355 1   91180355
7.449   2.023e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_91180355 L2_None_chr1_-_91180355 1   91180355
7.151   9.129e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_91180355 L2_None_chr1_-_91180355 1   91180355
7.149   9.201e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_91182695 L2_None_chr1_-_91182695 1   91182695
7.189   7.534e-11   L2_None_chr1_-_91183491 L2_None_chr1_-_91183491 1   91183491
```

I tried in R the function `match` but this was not helping me completely...

Comment: Could you take the time to format your question/code properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should dot it:

```
 merge(dat,dat1,by.x='tag',by.y='tag')
                      tag   stat stat.1   P.value   V2        V3
1  L2_None_chr1_-_109092036 0.3049  7.464 1.875e-11 chr1 109092034
2  L2_None_chr1_-_109092036 0.2961  7.448 2.105e-11 chr1 109092034
3  L2_None_chr1_-_109092036 0.2934  7.347 3.389e-11 chr1 109092034
4  L2_None_chr1_-_109092036 0.2961  7.245 5.668e-11 chr1 109092034
5  L2_None_chr1_-_109957962 0.6682  7.284 4.664e-11 chr1 109957879
6  L2_None_chr1_-_109957962 0.6682  7.284 4.664e-11 chr1 109957879
7  L2_None_chr1_-_159842839 0.3933  7.363 3.127e-11 chr1 159842779
8  L2_None_chr1_-_159842839 0.3808  7.284 4.672e-11 chr1 159842779
9  L2_None_chr1_-_169972458 0.2993  7.170 8.278e-11 chr1 169972444
10 L2_None_chr1_-_203626998 0.3312  7.817 3.075e-12 chr1 203626983
11 L2_None_chr1_-_203626998 0.3312  7.817 3.075e-12 chr1 203626983
12    L2_None_chr1_-_569826 0.6140  7.616 9.742e-12 chr1    569802
13    L2_None_chr1_-_569826 0.6411  7.580 1.037e-11 chr1    569802
14    L2_None_chr1_-_569826 0.5755  7.275 4.871e-11 chr1    569802
15   L2_None_chr1_-_6546011 0.6893  7.260 5.255e-11 chr1   6545930
16  L2_None_chr1_-_91180355 0.3136  7.529 1.350e-11 chr1  91180310
17  L2_None_chr1_-_91180355 0.3262  7.449 2.023e-11 chr1  91180310
18  L2_None_chr1_-_91180355 0.2980  7.151 9.129e-11 chr1  91180310
19  L2_None_chr1_-_91182695 0.2999  7.149 9.201e-11 chr1  91182572
20  L2_None_chr1_-_91183491 0.5383  7.189 7.534e-11 chr1  91183389
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the linux `join` command. `man join` is a start, and your command will be smth like this

```
join -1 4 -2 1 <(sort FILE1) <(sort FILE2)
```

`-1` and `-2` specify the fields in the corresponding files that will be used for the match. You don't need to `sort` if the files are already sorted.